# How do I make two floating divs smoothly follows each other when moving using transition?

Tags: css, transition, sidebar, smoothing

I need some help with a little bit of CSS coding. What I am currently attempting to make is a sidebar that slides in (like on mobile pages) but instead of making the position absolute I have made the two divs float inside a wrapper.

My explaining skills are not that great, so I will proceed by giving you a pretty simple example to demonstrate.

The HTML:

```
<!-- Using to toggle the sidebar -->
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" hidden="hidden">

<!-- The wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- The content -->
  <div class="content">
    <label for="toggle">Show</label>
    <!-- Content goes here -->
  </div>

  <!-- The sidebar -->
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <label for="toggle">Hide</label>
    <!-- Sidebar content goes here -->
  </aside>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Just some general settings */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* When toggle - do this */
#toggle:checked + .wrapper > .content {
  margin-left: -25%;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

/* The wrapper */
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

/* The content */
.wrapper > .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

/* The sidebar */
.wrapper > .sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: #27ae60;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

As you can see when you either click "Show" or "Hide" the sidebar does not appear or disappear smoothly. **Is there any way I can make it smooth?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just do a toggle a class on the body tag. For example `.sidebar-open`:

```
.wrapper,
.sidebar {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}    

.sidebar-open .wrapper,
.sidebar-open .sidebar {
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}
```